# HibernateQueryException on this line

Tags: java, hibernate

**I am getting the following Exception**

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateQueryException: unexpected
char: '{'

 hibernateTemplate.find("select new com.XXX.application.modules.service.vo.ServiceRuleVO( A.id, A.serviceTypeId,  A.petLocationId, A.startDate,  A.endDate,  A.status, A.recurFrequency, A.recurCount,  A.recurInterval,  A.recurByDays, A.recurByMonths,  A.recurByMonthDay,  A.billable, A.modifiedBy,  A.modifiedTime, {B} ) from ServiceRule as A left join ServicePet as C on C.serviceRuleId=A.id left join Pet as B on B.id=C.petId order by FROM_UNIXTIME(A.startDate) desc");
```

Constructor inside VO Class

```
public ServiceRuleVO(int id, int serviceTypeId, int petLocationId,
        int startDate, int endDate, int status, String recurFrequency,
        int recurCount, int recurInterval, String recurByDays,
        String recurByMonths, int recurByMonthDay, int billable,
        int modifiedBy, int modifiedTime, List<Pet> petList) {

    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.serviceTypeId = serviceTypeId;
    this.petLocationId = petLocationId;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.status = status;
    this.recurFrequency = recurFrequency;
    this.recurCount = recurCount;
    this.recurInterval = recurInterval;
    this.recurByDays = recurByDays;
    this.recurByMonths = recurByMonths;
    this.recurByMonthDay = recurByMonthDay;
    this.billable = billable;
    this.modifiedBy = modifiedBy;
    this.modifiedTime = modifiedTime;
    this.petList = petList;
}
```

How can i set the data to the VO class using hibernateTemplate

Comment: It's complaining about the `{B}`. Does it have to be a parameter or ... ?

Comment: Try replacing `{B}` with simply `B`.

Comment: sorry did't worked i tried {B}, {B.*}, B. Everything fails with same error

Comment: @kocko yes it do hav a parameter. B is an arraylist which contains multiple rows of data

Comment: I'm not sure whether lists are allowed in such constructors or not, but anyways your `B` would be a single element, not the list itself. If `C` had property of type `List<Pet>`, e.g. `pets`, you could try `C.pets` instead.

Comment: @Thomas but i need multiple rows of data at B..!!

Answer (score 0):

You can't just specify a List in the query like that.  There is a setParameterList(String, Object[]) method for the HibernateQuery.  That may do what you are looking for.  Check the API Docs: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.2/api/org/hibernate/Query.html

**EDIT:**

He's an example of building a (more simple) query that takes a List parameter.  Hopefully this can guide you in modifying yours:

```
Query query = session.createQuery("from Employee e join e.skillGroups as s where s in (:skillGroups)");
// skillGroups must be a Collection type
query.setParameterList("skillGroups", skillGroups);
query.setParameter("skillGroupsLength", skillGroups.length);
List list = query.list();
```

Comment: can we do it with hibernate template..??

Comment: With the caveat that I am not a Spring guy... If I understand your comment correctly, the HibernateTemplate was dropped several years ago as I recall; maybe around the Spring 3.1 timeframe. I'll edit my answer with my recommendation..